# How to go to specific tab in el-tabs when the button is clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tabs, vue-component, element-ui

I have tabs using element ui:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
    <el-tab-pane label="User" name="first">User</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Config" name="second">Config</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Role" name="third">Role</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Task" name="fourth">Task</el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
  <button @click="handleTab"></button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        activeName: 'first'
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleClick(tab, event) {
        console.log(tab, event);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

And when I click the button handleTab I want to go to the first tab which is User in this example. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create method `handleTab` which you already call on button click and in that method set value of `activeName` to `first`.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <el-tabs v-model="activeName" @tab-click="handleClick">
    <el-tab-pane label="User" name="first">User</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Config" name="second">Config</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Role" name="third">Role</el-tab-pane>
    <el-tab-pane label="Task" name="fourth">Task</el-tab-pane>
  </el-tabs>
  <button @click="handleTab">Open User</button>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        activeName: 'first'
      };
    },
    methods: {
      handleClick(tab, event) {
        console.log(tab, event);
      },
      handleTab() {
        this.activeName = 'first';
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple set value of v-model in el-tabs by name of el-tab-pane which you want to active